# I want to run dask.dataframe by using jython

Tags: python, jython, dask

I want to run dask in java process by using jython.

I installed dask[complete] by using pip command.

but, java process raise ImportError: dask

so how I can fix this bug?

```
package test;
import org.python.core.*;
import org.python.util.*;
public class TestJython {
private static PythonInterpreter pi;

public static void main(String[] args) throws PyException {
    pi = new PythonInterpreter();
    PySystemState sys = pi.getSystemState();
    sys.path.append(new PyString("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"));
    pi.exec("import dask.dataframe as dd");
    }
}
```

error log :

```
Exception in thread "MainThread" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(e) + '\n\n' + msg)
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `PythonInterpreter` isn't initialized with the correct `PYTHONPATH` setup. This is not an issue with Dask, but with how you're initializing `PythonInterpreter`. Looks like you may need to set the `python.path` system property, or use the `JYTHONPATH` environment variable: https://www.stefaanlippens.net/jython_and_pythonpath/.

Note that the dask team has no experience running dask in Jython, and cannot guarantee that things will work, or be performant.